# Check how many users have got the In-App updates screen

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-update, google-play-core

I have implemented In-App updates in android. I want to check that how many users have got Flexible or immediate screen. Is there any way to check this?

Comment: there is no explicit tracking API in the in-app update feature. 
but you can your analytics tracker to track this event [flexible - immediate].

Comment: @ahmed ewess: How can I add custom analytics to track this? Is there any way.

Comment: if you're using any analytics platform like firebase analytics or adobe analytics, so you can track if the in-app update dialog appears or not using track event/screen options 
you also can track if the user press on update or cancel